# How to switch to PIN in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

On a Windows 10 laptop, I have set a PIN, but during login, I am asked to enter a password. I see no option on the login screen to change to entering a PIN.

How do I switch to entering a PIN @ login in Windows 10 please?

Comment: At the login screen there is an icon to switch from password to pin, if there is no second icon, then you have to configure the pin again.  How you switch from pin to password login is well documented.

Comment: Funny that Google cannot find said documentation ;-)

Comment: (certainly worthy of a down vote with no explanation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to reset my PIN for PIN to be a login option.